# Problem running dpkg due to bad gconf dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, gconf

I cannot run any `apt` operations due to some dependency issues.

If I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gconf-service-backend : Depends: libgconf-2-4 (= 3.2.6-4ubuntu1) but 3.2.6-4.1 is installed
 gconf2 : Depends: gconf-service (= 3.2.6-4.1)
 libgconf-2-4 : Depends: gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-4.1) but 3.2.6-4ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But on running `apt --fix-broken install` I get this:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gconf-service_3.2.6-4.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/2/libgconfbackend-evoldap.so', which is also in package gconf-service-backend 3.2.6-4ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gconf-service_3.2.6-4.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried running `sudo dpkg configure -a` but got the following:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on gconf-service (= 3.2.6-4.1); however:
  Version of gconf-service on system is 3.2.6-4ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic (4.13.0-37.42) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgconf-2-4:amd64:
 libgconf-2-4:amd64 depends on gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-4.1); however:
  Version of gconf2-common on system is 3.2.6-4ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libgconf-2-4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.13.0.37.40); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 4.13.0.37.40); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
 libgconf-2-4:amd64
 linux-image-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-signed-generic
```

It looks like I'm firmly in dependency hell due to the odd difference between gconf 3.2.6-4.1 and 3.2.6-4ubuntu1. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force overwrite of the file.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/gconf-service_3.2.6-4.1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

If all odds to fix fails remove `gconf2`

```
sudo apt-get remove gconf2
```

You can in addition, remove other problematic packages that show up in the list with same behavior and finally `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`